# After launching the specified browser with Selenium RC, The test doesn't run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, htmlsuite

**PLEASE HELP, I'm out of Ideas!!!!!!**,

I'm having a problem executing my Selenium IDE created tests using Selenium RC's -htmlSuite command on any of my browsers(ie, ff and chrome).

When I run the following command in CMD, Windows 8:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -htmlSuite
>   "*googlechrome" "http://www.example.com"
>   "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\BasicTest.html"
>   "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\results.html"
>   -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0srebkp2.selenium"

The Browser successfully launches, BUT the selenese commands are **Not** being executed.

The Browser URL value when RC launches is:

> http://www.example.com/selenium-server/core/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&resultsUrl=../postResults&test=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fselenium-server%2Ftests%2FBasicTest.html

Any idea what the problem could be?...Please help.

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Comment: Posted below, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was that my selenium test "**BasicTest.html**" wasn't a test suite.

Since it  was a single test, the -html suite didn't recognize it. It only looks for a test suite to execute.

I had to put the "BasicTest.html" into a "**SeleniumTestSuite.html**" and referenced that instead.

So the new command looked like this:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -htmlSuite
>   "*googlechrome" "http://www.xxxx.com"
>   "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\SeleniumTestSuite.html"
>   "C:\Users\Tunji\Desktop\SeleniumTestsCoreFunctionality\results.html"
>   -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0srebkp2.selenium"

After that It ran like it was supposed to :). Hope that's clear enough.

Tunji